# Devexpress Gridwiew Toolbars Custom Buttons No reaction

Tags: devexpress, toolbars

I have a problem ,

Devexpress AspxGridwiew  ToolBars CustomButtons   Not working.?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lsFC.png)

**Event**

```
 protected void ASPxGridView1_CustomButtonCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomButtonCallbackEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ButtonID != "Detay") return;
        id = ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(ASPxGridView1.FocusedRowIndex, "ID").ToString();
        ASPxPopupDetay.PopupHorizontalAlign = PopupHorizontalAlign.WindowCenter;
        ASPxPopupDetay.PopupVerticalAlign = PopupVerticalAlign.WindowCenter;
        ASPxPopupDetay.Modal = true;
        ASPxPopupDetay.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
    }
```

**[ScreenCast](https://www.screencast.com/t/rexM3oiEU0s)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

AspxGridview.EnableCallBacks  =  False ;